# how to pass fix size array via interface in solidity 0.4.25

Tags: solidity, arrays, calldata, interfaces

I used the following code

```
interface test{
  function testfunction(uint[20] memory P, uint[20] memory Q) external returns(uint,bool,uint);
}
```

It gives the error `Location has to be calldata for external functions (remove the "memory" or "storage" keyword)`

and when I changes it to

```
interface test{
  function testfunction(uint[20] calldata P, uint[20] memory Q) calldata returns(uint,bool,uint);
}
```

It gives error `Expected ',' but got identifier function` , so what is the correct way declare this in interface, and also how to call that function from inside a function of same contract. please reply for the same solidity version.

Comment: The error-message tells you `remove the "memory" or "storage" keyword`. Why not just follow it???

Comment: "how to call that function from inside a function of same contract" - declare it `public` instead of `external` (and of course, in the contract itself, not in the interface).

Comment: when I removed the keyword `calldata` it worked, Thank You